# Show result of a form field without reloading page

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I want to use jQuery/AJAX to do the following...

I have a text box with a URL to an image. I want that image to appear in a separate DIV as the URL is inserted.
obviously before any submit button is pressed.

Comment: Surely you would need to do this on button click, as if you do it as the person is typing you will have a broken image until the url is complete? AJAX isn't required here.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: could just link up to a keyup event in the text box, you'd get a broken image but at least it'd be in real time.

Comment: Broken image is fine... it's a new record screen for a DB

Comment: As so as the focus leaves the text box, the event would fire... any handlers for that?

Answer (score 0):

To OP, you dont mention your exact time of do this job, but I write the process to append image to a url  div with url from a input box.

```
var url = $('input[type="text"]').val();

if($.trim(url).length) {

   $('DIV').append('<img src="'+ url +'" alt="image">');

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

if($.trim($('input[type="text"]').val()).length) {

   $('div').append('<img src="'+ $('input[type="text"]').val()+'" alt="image">');

}
});
```